# How do you display the answer to an equation in WxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to make a calculator in WxWidgets in CodeBlocks. I made the Buttons and now I wish to display the answer. How should I display the answer?

Comment: If you want to show it as a text, then VZ's answer is the way to go; however, if you want to show the `result` of an arithmetic operation, then you need to write a small parser, a good book would be: https://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, just use a `wxTextCtrl` with `wxTE_READONLY` style. This will allow the user to select (maybe parts of) the answer and copy it to the clipboard.

Of course, this is not at all the only possibility, but it's far from clear what do you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Can you use code to display the answer. For Example if I do the following equation; sum = a + b (sum,a,b are Variables), can I make a code like this; cout << sum << endl; ?

Comment: @JustinGeorge, you mean like in Scientific Calculator?

Comment: @JustinGeorge you can't use `cout` in GUI applications, it doesn't make sense (without redirecting it, anyhow, which is, incidentally supported, but I don't think you want to go there). If you're translating some non-GUI example program to a GUI one, you must realize that you can't do it statement by statement, but need to change the program structure.

Comment: @Igor No, I meant an Arithmetic Calculator